# How to send piped response in Next.js API using wkhtmltoimage?

Tags: javascript, next.js, wkhtmltoimage

I'm new to Next.js, and I'm trying to use [wkhtmltoimage](https://github.com/timstudd/node-wkhtmltoimage) but I can't seem to send the generated image stream as a response in my Next.js API.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const wkhtmltoimage = require('wkhtmltoimage').setCommand(__dirname + '/bin/wkhtmltoimage');


export default async function handler(req, res) {
  try {
    await wkhtmltoimage.generate('<h1>Hello world</h1>').pipe(res);
    
    res.status(200).send(res)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send({ error: 'failed to fetch data' })
  }
}
```

I know I'm doing plenty of stuff wrong here, can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're concatenating `__dirname` and `/bin/wkhtmltoimage` together, that would mean you've installed [the wkhtmltoimage executable](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) to `./pages/api/bin` which is probably not a good idea since the `pages` directory is special to Next.js.

We'll assume you've installed the executable in a different location on your filesystem/server instead (e.g., your home directory). It looks like the `pipe` function already sends the response, so the `res.status(200).send(res)` line will cause problems and can be removed. So the following should work:

```js
// ./pages/api/hello.js
const homedir = require("os").homedir();

// Assumes the following installation path:
//   - *nix:     $HOME/bin/wkhtmltoimage
//   - Windows:  $env:USERPROFILE\bin\wkhtmltoimage.exe
const wkhtmltoimage = require("wkhtmltoimage").setCommand(
  homedir + "/bin/wkhtmltoimage"
);

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  try {
    res.status(200);
    await wkhtmltoimage.generate("<h1>Hello world</h1>").pipe(res);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send({ error: "failed to fetch data" });
  }
}
```

Comment: How do i setCommand when calling from node_modules? I have installed the npm version of the wkhtmltoimage

Comment: @Bwrites [node-wkhtmltoimage](https://github.com/timstudd/node-wkhtmltoimage) is only a wrapper for the executable and doesn't include it — unless you actually see a `bin` directory inside the `./node_modules/wkhtmltoimage` directory or the `wkhtmltoimage` executable inside the `./node_modues/.bin` directory?

Comment: Oh! No, I don't actually see that. It's nowhere in `node_modules/bin` as well. Does a wrapper mean it allows you to use it in JS even if it's an exectuable? I get this error, btw `Error: spawn /node_modules/wkhtmltoimage ENOENT` does this mean all I have to do is install the executable, point to it, then I could finally use it in my application?

Comment: @Bwrites Yep, all you have to do is install it. The easiest way would be to download a prebuilt binary [here](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html). Then install it to your `$HOME/bin` directory just to test it out against the code I posted up there (you could always move it elsewhere once you get the hang of it).